# Abstracting the Request object

Tags: c#, abstraction

I'm running some basic unit tests on an MVC4 application. Within one of the main controller methods there is a call to Request.UserHostAddress.

However when I run my unit test it fails (Object null reference) which I presume is because the Request object has no context.

What's the bets thing to do in this situation. I read a suggestion about abstracting the Request object, but im not sure how, or whether this is the best approach?

Advice (and possible solution) would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you use a mocking framework ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the `ControllerContext` on your controller under test. This includes the `RequestContext`, which is what is used when you use `Request.UserHostAddress`. Then you just have to pass in a mocked `HttpRequestBase`.